# Ubuntu 20.10 ubuntu tty1 Login incorrect

Tags: raspberrypi

Let me start by saying what I'm trying to do with my rasp pi 4 B which is make my own vpn server.  I have 3 years of experience with various linux distros but can't even get a freshly written ubuntu server iso to login in with default credentials (Ubuntu Server 20.10 64 bit). Is the default not still username "ubuntu" password "ubuntu"?

Answer (score 0):

The default password for ubuntu is 'ubuntu' however if this is Raspbian/Raspberry pi then the default user is 'pi' and the password 'raspberry'.

I've been fooled myself by miss typing 'ubuntu' in either of the inputs..